# Can I find the limit of functions of two variables by the following way?

Tags: limits, functions

Prove that$$\lim_{{x,y}\to0,0}\frac{4x^3+6y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$$
Let $q=max[x,y]$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta$ such that $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta=\epsilon/10$ and
$$\left|\frac{4x^3+6y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{4q^3+6q^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\left|\frac{10q^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{10q(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le10\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<10\delta=\epsilon$$
i.e the limit exists and it equals 0.

Comment: I have trouble with $|10q^3|\le |10q(x^2+y^2)|$. Go polar.

Comment: @AndréNicolas If $q=x$, don't we have $q^2\le x^2+y^2$?

Comment: I agree. There is nothing wrong with the proof that I can spot. (other than it would have been nice if he'd used \varepsilon instead of \mathcal{E}).

Comment: Yes, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way will be as follows:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{4x^3+6y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right| &\leq 4\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|+6\left|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\
&\leq 4|x| + 6|y| \\
&\leq 10\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
\end{align*}